# How to show complex OData property types in sap.ui.comp.smarttable.SmartTable?

Tags: annotations, odata, sapui5

I'm working on a SAPUI5 application and want to display a list of data records using a [sap.ui.comp.smarttable.SmartTable](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.comp.smarttable.SmartTable.html).

Fiddling around with the [Smart Table samples from the SAPUI5 Explored App](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/entity/sap.ui.comp.smarttable.SmartTable/samples) I was able to get the Smart Table running against an OData service provided by a mock server.

**Smart Table in XML view**

```
<smartTable:SmartTable tableType="ResponsiveTable"
    entitySet="RecordSet" enableAutoBinding="true" />
```

**Corresponding lines of metadata.xml**

```
<Schema Namespace="my.namespace" sap:schema-version="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/09/edm">

    <ComplexType Name="ShortReference">
        <Property Name="Type" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" sap:label="Reference type" />
        <Property Name="Key" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" sap:label="Reference key" />
    </ComplexType>

    <EntityType Name="Record" sap:label="Record" sap:content-version="1">
        <Key>
            <PropertyRef Name="RecordID" />
        </Key>
        <Property Name="RecordID" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" sap:label="Record ID" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false" />
        <Property Name="ShortReference" Type="my.namespace.ShortReference" />
    </EntityType>

    <EntityContainer Name="my.namespace.Entities" m:IsDefaultEntityContainer="true" sap:supported-formats="atom json xlsx">
        <EntitySet Name="RecordSet" EntityType="my.namespace.Record" />
    </EntityContainer>

    <!-- Default columns shown by Smart Table -->
    <Annotations Target="my.namespace.Record" xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edm">
        <Annotation Term="com.sap.vocabularies.UI.v1.LineItem">
            <Collection>
                <Record Type="com.sap.vocabularies.UI.v1.DataField">
                    <PropertyValue Property="Value" Path="RecordID" />
                </Record>
                <!-- The following doesn't work - it won't be shown in a Smart Table column -->
                <Record Type="com.sap.vocabularies.UI.v1.DataField">
                    <PropertyValue Property="Value" Path="ShortReference/Key" />
                </Record>
                <Record Type="com.sap.vocabularies.UI.v1.DataField">
                    <PropertyValue Property="Value" Path="ShortReference/Type" />
                </Record>
            </Collection>
        </Annotation>
    </Annotations>
</Schema>
```

As you can see a data record has a complex property of type `my.namespace.ShortReference`. I want the two properties to appear in the Smart Table as separate columns to be able to filter them.

I did have little success by using the `<customData>` aggregation as follows,
but as I'm having more than this single complex entity (including a complex entity with another complex entity) I'm searching for a simpler and more robust way to achive that goal. Furthermore, with `<customData>` my filtering ability in the p13n dialog is limited (no possibility to use filter like `contains`, `starts with` etc.).

**Smart Table with custom data**

```
<smartTable:SmartTable tableType="ResponsiveTable"
    entitySet="RecordSet" enableAutoBinding="true" >
    <Table>
        <!-- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32114675/sapui5-smart-table-how-to-inject-my-own-column-into-smart-table-default-colum -->
        <!-- Smart Table Developer Guide: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/bed8274140d04fc0b9bcb2db42d8bac2.html -->
        <columns>
            <!-- Reference -->
            <Column>
                <customData>
                    <core:CustomData
                        key="p13nData"
                        value='\{
                            "columnKey":        "ReferenceType",
                            "leadingProperty":  "ShortReference/Type",
                            "sortProperty":     "ShortReference/Type",
                            "filterProperty":   "ShortReference/Type",
                            "columnIndex":      "9"
                        }' />
                </customData>
                <Label text="Reference type"/>
            </Column>
            <Column>
                <customData>
                    <core:CustomData
                        key="p13nData"
                        value='\{
                            "columnKey":        "ReferenceKey",
                            "leadingProperty":  "ShortReference/Key",
                            "sortProperty":     "ShortReference/Key",
                            "filterProperty":   "ShortReference/Key",
                            "columnIndex":      "10"
                        }' />
                </customData>
                <Label text="Reference key"/>
            </Column>
        </columns>
        <items>
            <ColumnListItem>
                <cells>
                    <Text text="{ShortReference/Type}" />
                    <Text text="{ShortReference/Key}" />
                </cells>
            </ColumnListItem>
        </items>
    </Table>
</smartTable:SmartTable>
```

**So, is this even possible to achieve? Or do I have to flatten my OData entity?**

I would also change to a normal `sap.m.Table` if it's easier. I have chosen the Smart Table because of it's sorting, filtering, grouping abilities and the variant management (I need all of those).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have searched for a solution for a while, but I haven't found a satisfactory solution matching my entity structure above.

Therefore I have to answer my questions as follows

- **So, is this even possible to achieve?** No.
- **Or do I have to flatten my OData entity?** Yes.

My list gives an overview over a specific record set an navigates to a detail page. In my overview list I don't need every property, so I have created a new entity `RecordOverview` to run my Smart Table against.

**metadata.xml** (showing additions and changes only)

```
<Schema Namespace="my.namespace" sap:schema-version="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/09/edm">

    ...

    <EntityType Name="RecordOverview" sap:label="Record" sap:content-version="1">
        <Key>
            <PropertyRef Name="RecordID" />
        </Key>
        <Property Name="RecordID" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" sap:label="Record ID" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false" />
        <Property Name="ReferenceKey" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" sap:label="Reference key" />
    </EntityType>

    <EntityContainer Name="my.namespace.Entities" m:IsDefaultEntityContainer="true" sap:supported-formats="atom json xlsx">
        <EntitySet Name="RecordSet" EntityType="my.namespace.Record" />
        <EntitySet Name="RecordOverviewSet" EntityType="my.namespace.RecordOverview" />
    </EntityContainer>

    <!-- Default columns shown by Smart Table -->
    <Annotations Target="my.namespace.RecordOverview" xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edm">
        <Annotation Term="com.sap.vocabularies.UI.v1.LineItem">
            <Collection>
                <Record Type="com.sap.vocabularies.UI.v1.DataField">
                    <PropertyValue Property="Value" Path="RecordID" />
                </Record>
                <Record Type="com.sap.vocabularies.UI.v1.DataField">
                    <PropertyValue Property="Value" Path="ReferenceKey" />
                </Record>
                ...
            </Collection>
        </Annotation>
    </Annotations>
</Schema>
```

However, a nice (side) effect is I don't need to specify the columns in my XML view anymore.

**XML view**

```
<smartTable:SmartTable entitySet="RecordOverviewSet" enableAutoBinding="true">
    <Table>
        <items>
            <ColumnListItem vAlign="Middle" type="Navigation" press="onListItemPressed" />
        </items>
    </Table>
</smartTable:SmartTable>
```