# SAPUI5: How can I set formatter for P13n items when I do a grouping?

Tags: sapui5

I made a sap.m.List, and I used a P13n dialog to group the data. While I show the ids of the items in the list by a formatter function to remove its zeros when I group the items with P13n the formatter function of the list items does not work for group titles.

Look at the current picture:

[image]

Does anyone know how can we set formatter for grouping titles in a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `vGroup` of [`sap.ui.model.Sorter`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.Sorter) to specify your own grouping logic, like grouping key and custom grouping title .

Please read and run the below code snippet. Hope it helps.

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>Mobile App with XML View with JSON Data</title>

  <script id='sap-ui-bootstrap'
    src='https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js'
    data-sap-ui-theme='sap_belize'
    data-sap-ui-libs='sap.m'
    data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax='complex'></script>

  <script id="myXml" type="text/xmldata">
   <mvc:View xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m" controllerName="myController" displayBlock="true">
    <App>
     <Page title="Test">
      <List id="testList"
       items="{
        path: '/values',
        sorter: {
         path: 'id',
         descending: false,
         group:'.getGroup'
        }
       }"
       mode="MultiSelect">
       <StandardListItem
        title="{documentation}"
         />
      </List>
     </Page>
    </App>
   </mvc:View>
  </script>

  <script>
   sap.ui.controller("myController", {
    onInit: function() {
     var data = {
      values: [
       {id:"0000129",  documentation: "123"},
       {id:"0000126",  documentation: "140"},
       {id:"0000127",  documentation: "141"},
       {id:"0000126",  documentation: "145"},
       {id:"0000127",  documentation: "161"}
      ]
     };

     // create a Model with this data
     var model = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
     model.setData(data);
     
     this.getView().byId("testList").setModel(model); 
     
    },
    
    getGroup : function(oContext) {
     var name = oContext.getProperty("id");
     return {
      key: name,
      text: "Custom Title " +name.replace(/^[0]+/g,"")
     };
    }
   });
   sap.ui.xmlview({ viewContent: jQuery('#myXml').html() }).placeAt("content");
  </script>

 </head>
 <body id='content' class='sapUiBody'>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi @Allen. I have a question. Is it possible to use your method with smart tables? 
I have a column that I have to remove its leading zeros. The problem is that when it is grouped then we have the leading zeros in the header rows. How can I pass this function to smart table in UI5?

Comment: What's your table type behind your SmartTable? I guess you can do some trick in the event handling of beforeRebindTable.

Comment: I use a logic like the answer in the following link:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32114675/sapui5-smart-table-how-to-inject-my-own-column-into-smart-table-default-colum

Comment: ResponsiveTable should be sap.m.Table which extends 
sap.m.ListBase like sap.m.List. You can try the same solution

Comment: The problem is I don't know how to use your method in XML view with smart table. If you help me I would be appreciate. What do I have to add to my XML view?

Comment: Also I don't have grouping by default. User can select it by p13n dialog.

Comment: I guess for smarttable, the grouping is done by backend. Please check the http request for grouping action.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162965/discussion-between-mahdi-jaberzadeh-and-allen).

Answer (score 1):

I finally found out how I can use vGroup for smart table:

Question

How do I format the group headers shown in SmartTable of type ResponsiveTable (sap.m.Table)? And why is a technical key shown instead of a description when grouping is done in SmartTable of type ResponsiveTable?

Answer:

Grouping in ResponsiveTable is done by sorting table entries. You can define your own formatting for the group title in ResponsiveTable by specifying a group function for the first sorter.

For more information on how this can be done, see the sample.

When using the SmartTable control, you can use the beforeRebindTable event and get available sorters using the bindingParams (event parameter). Check if the first sorter there has a group.

```
onBeforeRebindTable: function(oEvent) {
    var mBindingParams = oEvent.getParameter("bindingParams");
    var oSorter = mBindingParams.sorter[0];
 //Check if sorter is for Grouping
    if(oSorter.vGroup){
```

There are two options. The first option looks like this:

```
//Replace the Group function
        oSorter.fnGroup = this.mGroupFunctions[oSorter.sPath];
```

You can also do the following:

```
//Replace the Grouping sorter itself        
        mBindingParams.sorter[0] = new Sorter(oSorter.sPath, bDescending, this.mGroupFunctions[oSorter.sPath]);
 }
```

Source: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/bed8274140d04fc0b9bcb2db42d8bac2